# How to swap places left to right of a few <option>, not all of them from within <select> using toggle button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html-select

How do I make a few `<option>` LangLEFT to switch position with a few `<option>` LangRIGHT and vise versa using a ON/OFF or LEFT/RIGHT toggle button or by using a `radio` button or a `check` box or another `select` menu.

I want a few `<option>` LangLEFT  to tugle with a few `<option>` LangRIGHT and swap places, without swap places of the `<select>` names codes.

**NOTE: Only a few `<option>` should switch places, NOT all `<option>`.**

**EXAMPLE: The "language value" should swap places, but the "auto value" should NOT.**

**HTML:**

```
<textarea name="uLEFT" cols="71" rows="7" wrap="physical" id="SeekBoxLEFT"></textarea> 

<textarea name="uRIGHT" cols="71" rows="7" wrap="physical" id="SeekBoxRIGHT" ></textarea>

<select name="LangLEFT">
<option selected value="auto">Auto Identify language</option>
<option value="en">English</option>
<option value="ru">Russian</option>
</select>


<select name="LangRIGHT">
<option value="en">English</option>
<option value="ru">Russian</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
  $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#right").on("click",function(){
      $("#left_select").insertAfter("#right_select");
      });
      $("#left").on("click",function(){
      $("#right_select").insertAfter("#left_select");
      });
   });
```

```html
 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <input type="button" id="right" value="Change To Right" >
 <input type="button" id="left" value="Change To Left" >

         <select id="left_select" name="LangLEFT">
          <option selected value="auto">Auto Identify language</option>
          <option value="en">English</option>
          <option value="ru">Russian</option>
         </select>
         <select id="right_select" name="LangRIGHT">
          <option value="en">English</option>
          <option value="ru">Russian</option>
         </select>
```