# How to switch the selected values between two select elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I switch the selected values of 2 `select` html elements that contain the same information.

The current scenario is the following: select the language to translate from and then to translate to.
To make it easier for the user, I want to offer the possibility to switch the source language to the target language and vice versa.

A simplified version of the HTML markup is the following one:

```
<select name="LangA">
    <option value="en">English</option>
    <option value="es">Spanish</option>
    <option value="sv">Swedish</option>
    <option value="tr">Turkish</option>
    <option value="uk">Ukrainian</option>
</select>

<select name="LangB">
    <option value="en">English</option>
    <option value="es">Spanish</option>
    <option value="sv">Swedish</option>
    <option value="tr">Turkish</option>
    <option value="uk">Ukrainian</option>
</select>
```

The languages are the same for both `select` elements. The feature I am trying to implement is very similar to google translations switch languages arrow.

The reason is that the boxes are for a translation textarea. The entire code is much bigger with much more languages, I only took out what is needed for the sake of keeping it short.

Comment: AndyTurner why did I get a "-" for the question?

Comment: What have you tried? Nothing should stop you from assigning the hardcoded names just like that. For the question for the downvote, read the arrow down, it mentions clearly why people should downvote or not (no research effort, not usefull or unclear)

Comment: It is not unclear, but the question is complicated. I edited it a bit now, you down voted just 2 seconds after i posted it, I did not even have time to take a look at it and edit it a bit.

Comment: There is no script shown in your question. Showing nothing but requirements looks like a free code request. - Then, what would be the trigger to switch the names... A button? a `change` event? Your best attempt to achieve it would show something about it.

Comment: Assign each element to a variable. Then use `.attr()` to change the `name` attribute of each of them.

Comment: Its okay to down vote, but not after 2 seconds of posting it. Now it is more clear telling you exactly what I mean.

Comment: You still haven't shown what you tried. We're not here to do your coding for you, but we'll help you fix your code.

Comment: Is not the HTML ``<option>`` codes, code script? Now it is in more detail. I did not put JavaScript cause I do not even know were to begin in this case. I know how to switch places with each other, but not how to switch names with each other.
If I knew that i would not ask, would I?

Comment: SeekLoad, you also could have posted a good question at once. Your question also rather seems to be an XY problem, why would you want to change the names of the elements, what reason do you have? What will happen with the selects afterwards, maybe there is another way we can solve the problem you are having. And no, html options is markup, not script

Comment: Okay how can I explain it the best way. If you have who we say ``<select>`` boxes. One is named A and the other B. How do you make A to switch name to B and B to switch name to A?

Comment: SeekLoad, you have been given the answer already by @Barmar. I personally am more interested in the why, as that might show the real problem, and not what you try to do

Comment: okay I will put the reason on. the reason is that the boxes are for a translation textarea. The entire code is much bigger with much more languages. Anyway the translation needs to be able to switch direction without changing the option chosen. Example as the arrows in Google Translate https://translate.google.com/#es/en/test

Comment: I will add that to the question above

Comment: I'm pretty sure that just changing the `name` attributes is not a solution for this. You should show how the languages are selected to trigger the translation function.

Comment: I never got an answer for this by @Barmar. Show me were I did get that answer?

Comment: i got an answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44981212/how-to-swap-places-left-to-right-of-a-few-option-not-all-of-them-from-within/44981827#44981827 by @Osama BUT that is to another question of swapping pieces of the boxes, not the names.

Comment: @Barmar's answer is the 5th comment. Here above!

Comment: So you mean to switch the places of the options WITHOUT swapping the places of the select boxes themselves. I thought of that too, but I never got how to do so, I only got how to swap places of the entire boxes.

Comment: There is ONLY ONE comment on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44981212/how-to-swap-places-left-to-right-of-a-few-option-not-all-of-them-from-within/44981827#44981827
So were is this @Bramer you talk off? You must confuse me with somebody else or with another post I put about something else.

Comment: SeekLoad, its in this comment series. You were the only one talking about that other question. Anyhow, I posted an answer in plain javascript that should do the trick

Comment: @Icepickle You made my day, you are the only one who understood the question. I chated about this yesterday before posting it as a question today. That is why I got so frustrated that nobody understood the question although we have a webpage online who is a perfect example.

Comment: @Icepickle Thank you for the salvation now. You down voted me and you saved me this time. the other guys talking about that I had the answer before from somebody. I do not even know what he was talking about, since this was the first time I posted this question. I only chated before with another guy were I did not show codes in the chat.

Comment: SeekLoad, can I edit your question so that it becomes more clear to potential future readers of this question what you would like to ask? Maybe it can help you formulate your questions better in the future? (I cannot promise that you wouldn't get more downvotes though)

Comment: @SeekLoad "Is not the HTML <option> codes, code script?" No, it isn't. Your question is about how to write the Javascript that modifies the HTML, so you should have shown your attempted Javascript code. You say that you didn't even know where to begin, so I gave a hint in my comment. Even a beginning programmer should have been able to use that to get started, but you've shown no initiative on your own, you just want someone else to write it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have the same languages in both, you could simply change the selection from one box to the other. This script will read the current selected value on both select dropdowns, and then search the option in the other one when you click on swap.

If the languages are really on the same place, the easiest option I can think of would be this:

```
function swapBySelectedIndex( selector1, selector2 ) {
  // get both elements and save the selectedIndex of the first element
  var elem1 = document.querySelector(selector1),
      elem2 = document.querySelector(selector2),
      selectedOption1 = elem1.selectedIndex;

  // set the first element to the second elements selectedIndex
  elem1.selectedIndex = elem2.selectedIndex;
  // set the second elements' selectedIndex to the saved index
  elem2.selectedIndex = selectedOption1;
}
```

```js
function getSelectedOption( elem ) {
  return elem.options[elem.selectedIndex].value;
}

function setSelectedOption( elem, value ) {
  for (let i = 0; i < elem.options.length; i++) {
    elem.options[i].selected = value === elem.options[i].value;
  }
}

function swapByOptionValue( selector1, selector2 ) {
  var elem1 = document.querySelector(selector1),
      elem2 = document.querySelector(selector2),
      selectedOption1 = getSelectedOption( elem1 ),
      selectedOption2 = getSelectedOption( elem2 );
  setSelectedOption( elem1, selectedOption2 );
  setSelectedOption( elem2, selectedOption1 );
}

function swapBySelectedIndex( selector1, selector2 ) {
  var elem1 = document.querySelector(selector1),
      elem2 = document.querySelector(selector2),
      selectedOption1 = elem1.selectedIndex;
      
  elem1.selectedIndex = elem2.selectedIndex;
  elem2.selectedIndex = selectedOption1;
}
```

```html
<select name="LangA">
<option value="en">English</option>
<option value="es">Spanish</option>
<option value="sv">Swedish</option>
<option value="tr">Turkish</option>
<option value="uk">Ukrainian</option>
</select>

<select name="LangB">
<option value="en">English</option>
<option value="es">Spanish</option>
<option value="sv">Swedish</option>
<option value="tr">Turkish</option>
<option value="uk">Ukrainian</option>
</select>

<button type="button" onClick="swapByOptionValue('select[name=\'LangA\']', 'select[name=\'LangB\']')">Swap selected languages</button>

<button type="button" onClick="swapBySelectedIndex('select[name=\'LangA\']', 'select[name=\'LangB\']')">Swap selected languages (using selectedIndex)</button>
```